# running asp.net5 application using latest dnx version fails

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx, coreclr

I pulled the latest code from https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/tree/dev

Without making any changes to the code. I built the application for
dnx version : 1.0.0-rc2-16308        coreclr     x64

The application builds successfully , however when I try to run the application, 
I get the below error.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an     object.
   at Xunit.Runner.Dnx.Program.GetAvailableRunnerReporters()
   at Xunit.Runner.Dnx.Program.Run(String[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly     assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Please Note , The same code base worked successfully couple of days back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Changed , my question. it has to do something with the dnx and xunit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RC2 is not stable. Downgrade to RC1

https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/releases

Answer (score 2):

We're in the process of migrating from `dnx` to `dotnet`. The migration happens on the dev branch so all the code there might not compile or fail at runtime. This is most likely one of those cases.

From the callstack I assume you're trying to run the tests. In the dotnet world, we run tests a little different and we haven't got yet to MusicStore with the conversion.

Sorry for the inconvenience.